# Compute summation with a relative error of O(n^-2)

Tags: summation, asymptotics

$a(n) = \sum_{i \geq 0} a_i n^{-i}$, how can we compute the value of $a(n)^n$ with a relative error of $O(n^{-2})$?

Comment: First can you write it with an absolute error of $O(n^{-2})$?

Comment: I don't feel I can, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$
a(n) = a_0 + a_1 n^{-1} + a_2 n^{-2} + O(n^{-3})
$$

we have

$$
\begin{align}
\log a(n) &= \log a_0 + \log\left(1 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} n^{-1} + \frac{a_2}{a_0} n^{-2} + O(n^{-3})\right) \\
&= \log a_0 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} n^{-1} + \frac{a_2}{a_0} n^{-2} + O(n^{-3}) \\
&\qquad - \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a_1}{a_0} n^{-1} + \frac{a_2}{a_0} n^{-2} + O(n^{-3})\right)^2 + O(n^{-3}) \\
&= \log a_0 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} n^{-1} + \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{2a_0^2}\right)n^{-2} + O(n^{-3})
\end{align}
$$

so

$$
\begin{align}
a(n)^n &= \exp\left[n \log a(n)\right] \\
&= \exp\left[n \log a_0 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} + \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{2a_0^2}\right)n^{-1} + O(n^{-2})\right] \\
&= \exp\left[n \log a_0 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} + \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{2a_0^2}\right)n^{-1}\right] \exp\Bigl[O(n^{-2})\Bigr] \\
&= \exp\left[n \log a_0 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} + \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{2a_0^2}\right)n^{-1}\right] \Bigl(1+O(n^{-2})\Bigr),
\end{align}
$$

as desired.

Comment: Thank you Antonio, but I am computing the value of $a(n)^n$ here.

Comment: Whoops, I totally missed that.  My mistake.

Comment: @cinvro, I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you! You made it very clear. And I am wondering whether we can get the value with an absolute error? Why or why not?

Comment: Hmm, well by expanding the exponential as a power series we find that $$\begin{align}&\exp\left[n\log a_0 + a_1/a_0 + (a_2/a_0-a_1^2/2a_0^2)n^{-1}\right] \\&\qquad = e^{a_1/a_0} a_0^n \left[1+(a_2/a_0-a_1^2/2a_0^2)n^{-1}+O(n^{-2})\right],\end{align}$$ so, after expanding these brackets and multiplying this by $1+O(n^{-2})$, you'll see that the only way the absolute error could be $O(n^{-2})$ is if $a_0^n n^{-2} = O(n^{-2})$.  This is true if any only if $|a_0|\leq 1$.  Otherwise the only way to describe the absolute error is $O(a_0^n n^{-2})$.